# randomSplit don't respect specific weights PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm using PySpark and I'm looking for a way to randomly split an RDD into n equitable parts. Given :

```
RDD = sc.parallelize(range(50))
```

My code :

```
from itertools import repeat

def split_population_into_parts(rdd):

    N = 4

    weight_part = float(1) / float(N)

    weights_list = list(repeat(weight_part, N))

    repartionned_rdd = rdd.randomSplit(weights = weights_list)

    #And just to check what weights give, I did :
    for i in repartionned_rdd:

        print len(i.collect())


split_population_into_parts(rdd = RDD)
```

Knowing that **weights = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]**,  my code can give for exemple (as RDD lengths):

```
9
19
11
11
```

Why did randomSplit not respect weights here ? I want to have for exemple **12, 12, 12 and 14** as lengths, or **12, 12, 13 and 13**. What is the most efficient way to do this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Equal weights don't guarantee the same number of records. It only guarantees that each object has equal probability to be assigned to a specific subset.

If number of records is low you'll see fluctuations like here. This is normal behavior.

Comment: LostInOverflow : Thank you, but there is not really a way to have equitable parts ?

Comment: With good statistical properties and decent performance? Probably not. You can sort by random key, zipWithIndex and perform multiple filters with explicit range if you really need this.